# Image upload with Spring REST

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I want to upload image with RestTemplate client and get that POST request with Spring base REST sever and save on server. Can any one please help me to how to do this with my Spring base client and server. Thanks

Some of my Spring REST API base server methods are as below,

```
@RequestMapping(value="user/upload/{imageFile}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody User upload(@RequestBody User user, @PathVariable File imageFile, HttpServletResponse response) {

 // TODO - How I get this image and file and save, whether I can POST this image file with User object 

 }
```

Some of my remote client's Spring RestTemplate base codes are as below,

```
User newUser = new User();

Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
            vars.put("imageFile", imageFile);

            ResponseEntity<User> REcreateUser = restTemplate.postForEntity(IMC_LAB_SKELETON_URL + "/user/upload/{imageFile}", newUser, User.class, vars);

            User createUser = REcreateUser.getBody();

// TODO - How I can POST this image file as a parameter or content of the User object
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a piece of code I wrote time ago (you could pass the filename as a @PathVariable):

server side:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            //add your logics here
            //File newFile = new File("blablabla.xxx");
            //file.transferTo(newFile);
...
```

test with rest template:

```
@Test
public void testFileUpload() {

    String url = "http://blablabla.com/file";

    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("images/file.xxx");

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> mvm = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    mvm.add("file", resource);

    ResponseEntity<String> respEnt = rt.postForEntity(url, mvm, String.class);

    //logger.info("body: " + respEnt.getBody());
...
```

this bean is needed (I think it requires some apache commons library but I am not sure and don't remember now)

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="500000"/>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code u can upload multiple files,working fine

```
     <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                    id="fileUploadForm">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="entry input-group col-xs-3">
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" name="files" type="file">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

JS

```
     $(document).ready(function() {

$("#btnSubmit").click(function(event) {

    // stop submit the form, we will post it manually.
    event.preventDefault();

    fire_ajax_submit();

});

});

 function fire_ajax_submit() {

// Get form
var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];

var data = new FormData(form);

data.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data, testing");

// $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", true);
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
});

$.ajax({
    method : "POST",
    enctype : 'multipart/form-data',
    url : "lotConfig/lotImage",
    data : data,
    // http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects
    processData : false, // prevent jQuery from automatically
    // transforming the data into a query string
    contentType : false,
    cache : false,
    timeout : 600000,
    success : function(data) {

        jQuery('#lotImageget').html('');
        getAllLotiamges();
        $('#updateImage').modal('hide');

        /*
         * $("#result").text(data); console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
         * $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", false);
         */

    },
    error : function(e) {

        $("#result").text(e.responseText);
        console.log("ERROR : ", e);
        // $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", false);

    }
});

}
```

Spring controller

```
      @PostMapping(value = "/lotImage")
        public ResponseEntity<String> updateLotImage(
        @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, HttpSession session)
        throws IOException {
    logger.info("--got request to update Lot Image--");
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" , ");
    for (MultipartFile file : files) {
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            continue; // next pls
        }
        try {

            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            String resourceName = "app.properties";
            ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread()
                    .getContextClassLoader();
            InputStream resourceStream = loader
                    .getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
            try {
                prop.load(resourceStream);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            String image_path = prop.getProperty("LOT_DESTINATION_IMG");

            Path path = Paths.get(image_path
                    + file.getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(path, bytes);

            sj.add(file.getOriginalFilename());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    logger.info("--Image updated--");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Success", HttpStatus.OK);

}
```